# How to view the contents of a database in AWS RDS?

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services

I have a small mysql RDS database associated with an Elastic Beanstalk python application. I'd like to view the contents of the database  and download its contents onto my local machine. How can I do this? Can I also edit the database?

Answer (score 2):

To view the contents, you can access the database via [`dbshell` (More documentation here)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell)

```
$> python manage.py dbshell #This would be pulled from the settings file
```

To download the contents, it is not django specific. In the command line, you can do

```
mysqldump --user=<user> --password=<password> --host=<rds host> database_name > <database_name>.sql
```

Documentation on [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

and to load to a local database:

```
mysql -u <user> -p -h localhost <database_name> < <database_name>.sql
```